# Why are sequential TABLE elements displayed on new lines in browser?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html-table

I have 4 labels + radio buttons I want to display next to each other on the same line:

```
+--------+ +--------+ +--------+ +--------+
|  NONE  | |   NO   | |   Yes  | |  N/A   |
+--------+ +--------+ +--------+ +--------+
| Button | | Button | | Button | | Button |
+--------+ +--------+ +--------+ +--------+
```

Instead, each Label + Button is going onto a separate line in the browser (Chrome or MSIE 11).  There are no explicit newline elements in the HTML.  Why are they going onto their own line and how do I keep them together?
This is one part of a form in a COTS product.  I don't have full control over the generated HTML, CSS or JS.

As an extra bonus points question, why is jQuery automatically adding TBODY elements inside my TABLE?  I'm not doing it.

Here's the HTML I generate with jQuery:

```html
<span id="F1538.wrapper" class="fieldWidget">
       <table><tbody>
          <tr><td><label for="F1538">(None)</label></td></tr>
          <tr><td><input type="radio" name="F1538" value="0" checked="checked"></td></tr>
       </tbody></table>
       <table><tbody>
          <tr><td><label for="F1538">No</label></td></tr>
          <tr><td><input type="radio" name="F1538" value="782"></td></tr>
       </tbody></table>
       <table><tbody>
          <tr><td><label for="F1538">Yes</label></td></tr>
          <tr><td><input type="radio" name="F1538" value="783"></td></tr>
       </tbody></table>
       <table><tbody>
          <tr><td><label for="F1538">N/A</label></td></tr>
          <tr><td><input type="radio" name="F1538" value="784"></td></tr>
       </tbody></table>
    </span>
```

Comment: You're putting each element into its own row when you use `<tr>...</tr>` and you've created four separate tables.

Comment: `<span>` is an inline element but `<table>` is a block-level element. I think you'll want to use CSS's `display: flex;` for the parent element (which should be a `<div>` or `<section>` instead).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how tables work.

First of all, each `<table>` is a block element, so unless specifically told not to, the next element after a table, will show up below it.

Within the tables, each `<tr>` represents a Table Row (they stack on top of each other). And within each row, each `<td>` represents a column of that row (they show up one next to each other, within that row).

If you really want to use a `<table>`, you must put the labels in the first `<tr>` and all the buttons in the second.

You may want to explore other options (most people would say you absolutely should, since semantically, this is not what a table is for). You can use 4 `divs`, each containing label + button, and make them either `float` next to each other, or use `flex` to achieve that same effect.

Comment: Good explanation covering every relevant aspect!

Comment: Thanks to @Victoria Ruiz, I had a "well, duh" moment.  The (now) obvious answer is 1 table, 2 rows (Labels on first row, buttons on second), 4 cells per row.  I'm hesitant to try a DIV / SPAN or CSS based approach because of time constraints, I know how to do it with tables, and the solution has to work within a table-intensive COTS framework.